# Conditional formatting on Pivot table with Epplus

Tags: excel, pivot-table, epplus

I am trying to add conditional formatting on my pivot table created from Epplus bu i am not able to do it.

I can add the column colors on regular excel sheet by

```
using (var range = Pws.Cells[1,1,5,5])
{
    range.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colorValue);
}
```

But when i add the code on pivot table sheet and try to open it it gives a pop up message like "Do you want to replace the content of the destination cell in PivotTable?"

I think its adding the color on top of the pivot table value. Its my guess because i can see the value of pivot table when i dont add the color formatting.

Any one had this issue and is there any work around?

Comment: I've gotten that when I'm programmatically adding content to an area on the sheet that already has data. Thus, it asks for your permission to obliterate the previous content.